# What kind of screws are these?

Tags: screws, furniture

The other eight have been inserted with no problem. I think the female part wasn't cut properly. But if I can identify the screws maybe I can determine what to do next.

[image]

Comment: what does an inserted one look like?

Comment: Are you looking for a replacement cam lock nut, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/HARFINGTON-Furniture-Connector-Connecting-Fittings/dp/B0BM8ZVTJ6, to grab onto the heads? Or maybe a threaded insert, e.g. https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=23853, to grab onto the threads?

Comment: Can you better describe how/why it didn’t go in? This is probably a hard part to source.

Comment: Got a pic of the *female* piece?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[Steel Dowel M8x39.5mm, for Mamut Connector](http://siso.dk/products/knock-down-fittings/kd-systems/fuerte--mamut-jumbo-fix-zamak-oe35mm/steel-dowel-m8x39-5mm--for-mamut-connector)